# C: String e.g. "abcde123" to int 123

Tags: c, string, function, int, type-conversion

My question is very simple. Is there a function in C to convert a string to int, if there is an arbitrary amount of redundant charachters before the actual integer?

The question could be specified to cover two scenarios:
1) String with a space before the integer: "abcde 123"
2) String with any non-numeric charachter before the integer: "abcde:123"

Comment: Use `strspn()` to find the first numeric character, then use `atoi` or `sscanf` to parse the number starting from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isalpha` or `isdigit` from `ctype.h` to find the first digit, and then use `atoi` or `atol` or `atoll` or `strol` or `stroll` to convert to `int`, e.g.:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[] = "abcde123";

  char *p = str;
  while (isalpha(*p)) ++p;
  int i = atoi(p);
}
```

Note that "If the converted value [of `atoi` / `atol` / `atoll`] falls out of range of corresponding return type, the return value is undefined." ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi)).

Comment: Function atoi is unsafe. If the string cannot be represented in the type you get undefined behavior.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. And I presume one can also avoid including ctype, and even take advantage of atoi returning 0 if it's not able to convert. In my case, you see the numbers won't start with 0 as they are converted to positive integers. Cheers!

Comment: @2501 that is incorect. If no conversion could be made the function returns zero.

Comment: @Fredrik Don't twist my words. I never said if no conversion could be made, the behavior is undefined. I simply said if the value cannot be represented, i.e. the used inputs a large value, the behavior is undefined. This is correct, and I quote: *If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @Fredrik On a side-note: since you're claiming that atoi returns zero, please quote the part of the standard that specifies this. I think you're actually wrong here, since there is no such rule for atoi.

Comment: @tuple_cat The link you're quoting is wrong. atoi doesn't return an undefined value. An undefined value doesn't exist. The *behavior* is undefined. And if no conversion can be performed is not even an option for atoi. Either the string is converted, or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I prefer the [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) family of functions compared to `atoi` due to the error checking.

Comment: Since you're making numbers, I'd prefer the while to read:
  while (!isdigit(*p)) ++p;

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` family of functions can be used to do this. So I'll demonstrate first and explain afterwards:

```
int x;
scanf("%*[^0123456789+-]%d", &x);
```

The first format specifier is the `[]`. It designates a family of characters that `scanf` should accept. The leading `^` negates that, so anything *other* than that family is accepted for the specifier. And finaly, `*` is used to suppress actual input, so while the input stream is scanned for the pattern, no attempt will be made to assign it into anything.

Comment: Function scanf is unsafe. If the string cannot be represented in the type you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sscanf()` or you can use the `strtoll()`.

```
//char string1[] = "abcde:123";
    char string[] = "ab23cde:123";
    int values[4]; // specify the number of integers expected to be extracted
    int i = 0;
    char *pend = string;
    while (*pend) {
        if (isnumber(*pend)) {
            values[i++] = (int) strtoll(pend, &pend, 10);
        } else {
            pend++;
        }
    }

//you can use a forloop to go through the values if more integers are expected

        printf("%d \n",values[0]);
        printf("%d \n",values[1]);
```

> 23
>   123

Basically it does't matter the position of the integers in the string it will extract all of them.

Comment: `sscanf` is no safer than `scanf` in the regard that was commented. You kinda missed the point of that remark.

Comment: I don't see how `strtol()` is any less safe than `strtoll()`. Both set `errno` if the value is outside of the representable range.

Comment: @DavidBowling yea but `atol` and `atoi `not. Thanks for the correction